# RSpec 3 - raising an error on purpose to test it is rescued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Consider a simple method -

```
def my_method(users)
  eligible_users = []

  users.each do |u|
    # Go to the next user unless they are eligible
    next unless is_eligible?(u)

    begin
      update_user(u)
      eligible_users << u
    rescue
      puts "Error occured"
      # Prints some other stuff about error
      next
    end
  end
end
```

A key feature of this method is that it loops through users but continues to the next user even if a given user throws an error.

If I were writing spec tests for this, I'd love to pass an array of 3 users and purposely have it error out on the first user. I can then check that the 2nd and 3rd were still correctly processed.

How would I go about raising an error on purpose for only *one* of the result sets?

I was thinking I could stub `is_eligible?` and return an error for one of the result and `true` for the remainder -

```
allow_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:is_eligible?).and_return(
  raise StandardError.new,
  true,
  true
)
```

As expected, that doesn't work. Any other approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: how can one method return 3 values at the same time.

Comment: RSpec supports this syntax - if the method is called 3 times it will return each of those 3 responses in that order. Allows you to stub different return values each times it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly answer the question, but rather than doing a begin resuce thing,you can follow this approach,

- Make the update_user return true or false.
- Keep an array of users that falied to update.
- return an object like

`response: { status: "failure", message: "falied to update #{pluralize(failed_users_array.count, 'user')}", failures: failed_users_array.join(", ") }` for failures and

`response: { status: "success", message: "#{pluralize(users.count, 'user')} updated successfully" }` for all success.

now you can easily test,

- have two cases, one where you can test failures and when you can test all success.

Just stub the response object.

For raising errors, you have to do `.and_raise("some tezt or StandardError.new")` , thats in the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs).

Comment: Thanks. That solution is definitely a good workaround, although in the context of RSpec I'd still like to be able to know how I can raise arbitary errors as needed. I'm not sure every situation where one needs to raise an error can be worked around in such a clean manner :)

Comment: whynot just try and_raise(StandardError.new or "foobar")